# Deploying spring soap consumer Jaxb generated files on local Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jaxb

Good morning,

I'm trying to deploy a spring application on a local tomcat, using generated jaxb classes. The classes are contained in the build directory build/jaxb/archifant/wsdl in a subproject.
When I try to run the application on server, I get the following error:

```
error reading file D:\eclipse_rio_workspace\rio\06_Development\archifant-communication-for-spring\build\classes\jaxb
D:\eclipse_rio_workspace\rio\06_Development\archifant-communication-for-spring\build\classes\jaxb (access denied)
```

I followed the getting started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and use gradle as build tool. The subproject is set up as a dependency. How do I solve this? I checked file permissions and classpath of tomcat.

To me this looks like tomcat is trying to read a directory as file?

Comment: The `access denied` message would point towards permissions on the `D:\eclipse_rio_workspace\rio\06_Development\archifant-communication-for-spring\build\classes\jaxb` directory being incorrect. Does the user running tomcat have access to this directory?

Comment: Yes he should have access (I guess tomcat is run with my local user on Windows?).

Comment: If tomcat is run as a service it doesn't have to be running as your user. You can check this from the Windows Services administration tool.

Comment: It's started from within eclipse for development, not as a service :)

Comment: Then it should be your local user alright. Only other thing I can think is to manually delete the `build\classes` folder on the sub-project and do a clean build from within eclipse (checking that the output folder is re-created successfully of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Solved" it by moving the generated classes into a package in the source folder.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. You can mark your answer as 'accepted' so that it doesn't show in the unaccepted answer queues.

Comment: I can do that, in 19 hours ;)